# Animate an imageview out of the activity and bring a fragment into the activity from the bottom: Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I have a main activity, which has an imageview sliding in from the top.

I want to fade this imageview out with a delay of 2 seconds.
Then immediately have a fragment slide in from the bottom into the main activity.

**How do I fade an imageview out with a delay?**

**Where do I define the fragment, in the xml or new java class?**

**And how do I animate the fragment?**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout ml;
Animation uptodown;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    ml = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ml);
    uptodown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
    ml.setAnimation(uptodown);

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundcolour">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
       <!-- my imageview -->    
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

uptodown.xml in res/anim

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:duration="800"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a FrameLayout at end of your xml like:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and add your fragment to this frame layout like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        android.support.v4.app.Fragment newFragment;
                        newFragment = new YourFragment();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
```

add an slide animation like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

and add this to your code:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide_up);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
                        fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
                        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
                        ml.setAnimation(fadeOut);
                        frameLayout.setAnimation(slide_up);
                    }
                },2000);
```